# Load Redux Store from Server using Axios Request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I want to perist my redux store using Server session, and for that I implemented a Transformer for loading data and do a Request using Axios to get session data from server and put them in Redux

```
const SetTransform = createTransform(
  // transform state on its way to being serialized and persisted.
  (inboundState, key) => {
    // convert mySet to an Array.

    return { ...inboundState};
  },
  // transform state being rehydrated
  (outboundState, key) => {
    // convert mySet back to a Set.
    let state=null
    let x=1;
    let test= getUserSession().then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
        state= {...outboundState, ...result.data.user,isLoggedIn:result.data.isConnected}
        console.log(state)
        x=0
        return state;
    })

  }
  // define which reducers this transform gets called for.
);
```

and I added The transformer in Persist Config

```
const persistConfig = {
  transforms: [SetTransform],
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2 // see "Merge Process" section for details.
 };
```

but the error i am getting is that the Loaded state is undefined because the Request is asynchrounous and the rehydrating function doesn't wait untill request completed

SO is there any other implementation to make my store loaded from user session and how to do that ? 
Thank you

Comment: You can call the API to get the server session in the componentDidMount of your app and then update the reducer after your app has loaded with the default initial state from the server.

Comment: @Sunil so , I will initialise the store and do the Session fetch after that I will dispatch and Action to modify data in redux Store ?

Comment: This can be one of the approach. Yes, you initialize the store, then let you app and component load. At the very top level component in your app, you call the API in the componentDidMount to fetch the data and then dispatch an action to modify the data in the store. As soon as your store is modified, the app will re-render with the updated session data.

Comment: There is another approach as well utilizing server side rendering but that will be more complicated than this one

Comment: @Sunil , thanks I tried that and It's Working , I used onBeforeLift parameter of PersistGate to make the data fetching start as soon as the app is loaded, without using componentwillmount , But i want to know if there is a way to implement Async transformers for Redux-Persist

Comment: I am not really sure about it and so can't comment on it. Will update here incase I find anything on it!